# Remove the first occurrence of a given element in a list

Tags: list, haskell

I need to make a code that removes the first occurrence of an given element in a list. So far I have only managed to make the code remove every occurrence of the given element.

Her is my code rigth now:

```
rem2 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
rem2 xs y = [x | x <- xs, x /= y]
```

If i try:

```
rem2 "hello" 'l'
```

The code will returne "heo", while I want it to returne "helo". Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified definition of `delete`:

```hs
delete :: a -> [a] -> [a]
delete  _ []    = []
delete x (y:ys) = if x == y then ys else y : delete x ys
```

It uses the more general function `deleteBy` in the actual library. [Here is the source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#delete).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted. Do you by the way, know how the code could look like using list comprehensions?

Comment: @eriksen1110 list comprehensions apply the same function over all elements of a list. For this problem you want to remove only the first occurrence, so you can't use list comprehensions here.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with recursion here. If you reached the end of the list, then you return an empty list (1); if you are given a non-empty list `(x:xs)` and the head of the list `x` matched the item we are looking for (2), we return the tail of the list `xs`; and in case the item does not match (3), we yield `x` and recurse on the tail of the list `xs`.

This function thus looks like:

```
rem1 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
rem1 ls y = go ls
    where go [] = …                  -- (1)
          go (x:xs) | … = …          -- (2)
                    | otherwise = …  -- (3)
```

I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possibly solution, but not exactly what I wanted. The soulution is following:

```
import Data.List

rem1 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
rem1 xs y = delete y xs
```

So if anyone have a solution which don't include a built-in function, I will gladly hear it from you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a curiosity solution using list comprehensions as you wanted:

```
remfst :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] 
remfst a xs 
   | (j:_) <- 
     [ i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], i <- [i | x == a]]
   = [ x | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], x <- [x | i /= j]]
remfst _ xs = xs
```

Is it "disgusting"? In production code, sure. Here, it's just something to ponder about.

Now, we have

```
> remfst 'l' "helalo"
"healo"
```